# Is it okay to openly discuss one's past suicide attempts?

Tags: halal-haram, suicide

The [World Health Organization](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs398/en/) writes the following about suicide:

> Over 800,000 people die due to suicide every year. ... By far **the strongest risk factor for suicide is a previous suicide attempt**. ...  The prevention of suicide has not been adequately addressed due to a lack of awareness of suicide as a major public health problem and the **taboo in many societies to openly discuss it**.

For *suicide attempt survivors*, the general advice is to open up and talk about suicide.

> When you are ready, **it is important to talk about what has happened with people you trust. This allows others to be there for you and provides a chance to work out where to go from here.**  ([BeyondBlue.com.au](https://www.helpguide.org/articles/suicide-prevention/suicide-help-dealing-with-your-suicidal-thoughts-and-feelings.htm))

Aside from the general relief of simply having someone to talk to, other people should be aware of one's past suicide attempts so that they can help appropriately in the case of a future suicide attempt.  It's best not to wait until you're at the brink before starting the discussion, as it's hard to speak coherently during these crises.

However, suicide is a major sin in Islam (number 29 in Major Sins by [al-Dhahabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Dhahabi) ([pdf](http://www.islamguiden.com/arkiv/majorsins.pdf))) and talking about sins is forbidden in Islam:

> **It is prohibited (haram) and sinful to talk about sins, whether current or past, except when there is a Shariah-countenanced reason.**  Even when such a reason exists, if it is possible to mention something general (such as not mentioning oneself or any particular type of sins) then mentioning specific sins would remain sinful. This is because it is:  (1) obligatory to avoid  vain talk, and (2) obligatory to conceal one’s sins.  ([SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2009/08/23/1369/))

**Question**: Is it okay to openly discuss one's past suicide attempts?

It may be that discussing one's past suicide attempts in an effort to safeguard against future attempts might be considered a "Shariah-countenanced reason", especially if suggested by medical professionals.

The most relevant search hit was a question [Past Suicide Attempts Still Affect My Life](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-counselor/self-issues-ask-about-counselor/past-suicide-attempts-still-affect-life/) to an Islamic counsellor who doesn't quite address talking about past attempts directly: "...my advice at this point would be to talk to your mom about these feelings and ask her to help you get therapy."

Comment: If you think they'll be considerate, and expressing yourself will "safeguard" you against future attempts, then it's definitely encouraged. But you should be aware that for some, if you reveal such info too early in the relationship, that may scare them away if they're not emotionally strong (they may not be able to bear with the stress).
After all, if you're drowning and they want to help you, they should not only know how to swim, but they should be really good swimmers

Answer (score 1):

It's not only halal, but **it's highly encouraged.**

Allah (SWT) states in the Quran:

> And why should you not eat of that (meat) on which Allah's Name has been pronounced (at the time of slaughtering the animal), while He has explained to you in detail what is forbidden to you, **except under compulsion of necessity?** 6:119

This is a very known rule in Islam. **Necessity makes forbidden things permissible.** If the disclosure of suicide attempts helps you from actual suicide, then the disclosure of such a sin becomes obligated upon you.

This is similar to the common question of: A man dying of thirst in the desert but only has wine to drink? It becomes halal for him to drink that which is forbidden, because this is a case of absolute necessity.

Indeed suicide is a grave matter, and the disclosure of sins (haram) becomes halal.

And Allah (SWT) knows best.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely not haram to talk about one's suicide attempts, in particular to those who could help such as counselors or family/ friends, or those who would be directly effected by the consequences such as family members.

The quotes mentioned, especially the one which says it is absolutely haram to speak of past sins, seem to be speaking generally, and the latter appears to refer more to broadcasting or even boasting about one's sins past or present. The reason and circumstance for this would be that it is prohibited to scandalize oneself (and in turn one's family) or ruin one's reputation. I've heard this prohibition from a number of sources and it always refers to this application.

In the case of suicide, it is not merely a sin but a mortal danger, and therefore its risk to one's loved ones and community lies in *not* disclosing it but rather in hiding it and hence depriving others of the knowledge and thus ability to prevent future attempts. This need not be a public broadcast of the attempts but rather an admission privately to those concerned.

Also note that the act of suicide is haram when successful. The attempt which is unsuccessful is not suicide and cannot be prosecuted. Attempted suicide is haram, of course, but not a punishable crime. One could say suicide is the one crime that cannot be prosecuted in this life. The punishment in the Quran is with Allah, not earthly judges. Therefore it is a clear exception to the rule.

The rules in Islam always seek the best for Muslims and indeed for human beings. The best course in every respect in this case is disclosure, and it should in fact be made clear to Muslims that suicide attempts need counsel not punishment, and that disclosure is not only not haram, but should be encouraged, somewhat analogous to the less urgent matter of one who feels the urge to steal or gamble seeking help to prevent commission of the deed.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it is perfectly ok to discuss about that, but it is recommended only for police officers and detectives to discuss about that so they can solve the puzzle and soon when they have solved the puzzle, but it is better for you not, so that your mind will not be filled with all negative thoughts, because it makes you get lost and get despaired.

Secondly, if you want to have a wonderful life, you have to get rid from your mind all negative thoughts (e.g. suicide) because life is short.

Thirdly, you can open the discussion about this just to share some informations about this and finish, change the subject, because it is bad, and you have to fill up your mind with all good and halal thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

I feel people should feel free to discuss it with people close to them, like family, friends, a shaykh, or alternatively a professional counselor. or if certain behaviors or discussions of others will become a trigger for them if they do not let them know they were a survivor of suicide attempts, they should let them know even if they do not know them that well. i agree with another poster who said if suicide is a danger, the haram becomes halal.